# What's the difference between 3 and 4 quadrant triacs?

Tags: triac

I'm looking at triac datasheets, in particular this [datasheet for BTA16 series triac](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/7471.pdf). The "electrical characteristics" section is split into two parts: snubberless/logic level (3 quadrants) and standard (4 quadrants).

I have no idea what this is referring to. Are they different devices, as suggested by the column titles? Are they different operating modes? What is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NXP has [a good explanation](http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-NXP/DSANXP0100024.pdf) as to what the differences between 3-quadrant and 4-quadrant triacs are.

Summary: a 3-quadrant triac cannot be turned on in the fourth quadrant (T2 negative, G positive) which is beneficial when dealing with inductive loads - ringing caused by sudden turn-off could potentially turn on a 4-quadrant triac, necessitating snubbers and other protection means to prevent spurious conduction.

Comment: Link dead. Here's an alternative Link: http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-NXP/DSANXP0100024.pdf

Comment: Fixed. Yay for datasheetarchive, I don't think NXP / Nexperia carry any triacs at all any more...

Answer (score 2):

3-Q Triacs don't operate in 4th quadrant i.e positive gate current and negative load current. 
Please see the link I ve shared http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TRIAC_Equivalent_Circuit.png. 
You will get an insight of the working of a TRIAC